# lang parameter in Low Events with Publisher

Tags: date, low, low-events, localization, publisher

What does Low Events expect as a value for the `lang` parameter?

I've been trying to pass Publisher's `{publisher:current_language_id}`, `{publisher:current_language_code}` and `{publisher:current_language_prefix}`, but the dates will not get translated.
I even tried hardcoding `lang="2"`, but it won't get the english translation.

```
{exp:low_events:entries 
channel="channel" limit="3" 
lang="{publisher:current_language_id}" 
show_passed="yes" 
show_upcoming="yes" unit="custom" 
date_from="-1 year" 
date_to="+1 year"
}
```

Comment: Can you display {publisher:current_language_id} outside of the low_events template tag? Have you tried adding the parameter  parse='inward' to the low_events tag?

Comment: Yes. The tag works inside and outside the low_events loop tag.
No, parse="inward" doesn't do the trick

Comment: I even tried hardcoding lang="2", but it won't get the english translation.

Answer (score 0):

I misread Low events documentation.
The lang parameter is to be used in the variable and not in the low events tag.

`{myfield:start_date lang="{publisher:current_language_code}"}` works perfectly.